# Formula excel displays all data when one of the columns is selected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How formula excel to displays all data when one of the colomns is selected?
Example :

```
Name     Salary     City       Country
AdA       2         Sitahuan   Singa
Eda       4         Bandung    Asing
Oda       5         Mdn        Horas
ass       4         Pngam      Batan
```

Result

```
Name     Salary     City       Country
AdA       2         Sitahuan   Singa
Eda       4         Bandung    Asing
Oda       5         Mdn        Horas
```

I get the data when the second character = d, using formula this

```
=IF(MID(A1,2,1)="d",A1,"")
```

I want to display all data when the second character = d 
How formula to display all data when the second character = d

Comment: Put `=MID(A2,2,1)="d"` in another column and copy down, then sort the entire table on TRUE.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter rows on column A where the second letter = D

Comment: @ScottCraner  Filter rather than sort?

Comment: @ScottCraner i only get a one data, how i can display all data when i get name?

Comment: @QHarr yes allright

Comment: @QHarr yes filter on TRUE.

Comment: Use Scott's advice and have an end column with =IF(MID(A2,2,1)="d",TRUE,FALSE) then filter on TRUE.

Comment: @QHarr Your formula is superfluous. `= IF(<condition>,TRUE,FALSE)` is equivalent to just simply typing `= <condition>`, therefore ScottCraner's original comment accomplishes precisely what you typed here.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Yes. I wasn't paying attention.